# Помогите с задачей PHP + JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня есть **PHP** код в котором записывается данные из **БД**.

```
$count = 1500.55;
```

Я сделал функцию по примеру, чтобы не писать каждый раз отдельно.

```
function num($num){
   $element = $num;
   $element = round($element, 2);
   $element = split(".", '');
   $element = $element[0].".<sup>".$element[1]."</sup>";
}
```

Вывожу данные через функцию в **div**.

```
  <div class="data"><?php num($count) ?></div>
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы вот так получилось: **1500<sup>55</sup>**.
А потом через **JS** обновлять **div**.

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Мне нужно все значения после точки (запятой) взять в тег **<sup></sup>**.
Я не знаю  как вывести их таким образом чтобы получилось так :

Comment: Спасибо всё получилось ))

Answer (score 0):

Можно переписать функцию `num`

```
function num ($number) {
    return explode('.', $number)[0] . '<sup>'.explode('.', $number)[1].'</sup>';
}
```